# How can I write strings into a 2D ASCII character array?

Tags: c, arrays, string, multidimensional-array

Good day everyone, 
I'm currently learning C through youtube and I have minimal knowledge about arrays. Is it possible for me to use an array to designate a place inside a pattern. e.g In a 20x20box Could I ask the user to say where he would like to place his name tag or brandname? I'm also wondering if I can create a pattern for a shield and know where the user would want to place his coat of arms using strings and loops.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() 
{ 
    int i,j, choice;
    int Num=20;
    /*
    char brand[20][20]={{"BrandName"}};
    printf("where should the brandname be placed?")
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    if(choice==1)//prints it on the left for example?*/


    for(i=0;i<Num;i++) 
        { 
        for(j=0;j<Num;j++) 
        { 
        if(i==0||i==Num-1) 
        { 
        printf("*"); 
        } 
            else if(j==0||j==Num-1) 
            { 
            printf("*"); 
            } 
    else 
    { 
    printf(" "); 
    } 
    } 
    printf("\n"); 
    } 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome. What you ask is definitely possible, but can I suggest you do some tutorials on arrays so that you can feel confident to answer this question for yourself? Keep learning...

Comment: You might want to try simpler problems to solve if you're still in the very early stages of your learning trip. I don't think ascii art is a good problem to start with if you intend to learn about arrays. Just write programs that add, remove, modify, search, and basically manage arrays correctly before moving on

Comment: Yes, they should be possible.